# Excel PivotChart Treadline Horizontal Label

Tags: excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I've created a Pivot Chart from my Pivot Table, and added a Treadline to forecast the next four quarters. However, the horizontal axis for the new forecasts is blank. How can I add a label to the horizontal axis for the forecasted values (i.e. Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add four rows to your data table, one for each quarter, with the appropriate dates, but blank values for revenue (or whatever it is you're tracking).

Excel is looking for labels for the category and can't find any because it's not in your data.  Adding blank rows will provide the category labels without adding revenue figures.